# Trigger con variable en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Utilizo MYSQL 5.7.31 y estoy tratando de hacer un Trigger con variable:

```
Código SQL [-]
CREATE TRIGGER bi_lista BEFORE INSERT ON lista FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE miCol varchar(64);
  .....
END
```

Pero esto me genera un error:

```
Código SQL [-]
Error
CREATE TRIGGER bi_lista BEFORE INSERT ON lista FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE miCol varchar(14) 
MySQL ha dicho: 

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 3
```

Estoy tratando de guardar el historial de los cambios realizados en otra tabla donde se guarda:

- Fecha y Hora
- Usuario
- Nombre de la tabla
- Campo que se modifico
- Valor anterior
- Valor Nuevo

Trate de copiar este [ejemplo de firebird](https://firebird21.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/registrando-los-cambios-realizados-a-los-datos-de-una-tabla/):

```
CREATE TRIGGER BANCOS_ACTUALIZAR_BIUD FOR BANCOS
   ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
   POSITION 1
AS
   DECLARE VARIABLE lcUsuari TYPE OF D_NOMBRE30 COLLATE ISO8859_1;
   DECLARE VARIABLE ldTiempo TYPE OF D_FECHAHORA;
   DECLARE VARIABLE lcTablax TYPE OF D_NOMBRE30 COLLATE ISO8859_1;
   DECLARE VARIABLE lcOperac TYPE OF D_CHAR1 COLLATE ISO8859_1;
   DECLARE VARIABLE lnIdeTab TYPE OF D_IDENTIFICADOR;
   DECLARE VARIABLE lcColumn TYPE OF D_NOMBRE10 COLLATE ISO8859_1;
   DECLARE VARIABLE lcValorx TYPE OF D_NOMBRE254 COLLATE ISO8859_1;
BEGIN
 
   lcUsuari = CURRENT_USER;
   ldTiempo = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
   lcTablax = 'BANCOS';
 
   IF (INSERTING) THEN BEGIN
      lcOperac = 'I';
      lnIdeTab = NEW.BAN_IDENTI;
      lcColumn = 'BAN_NOMBRE';
      lcValorx = NEW.BAN_NOMBRE;
   END
 
   IF (DELETING) THEN BEGIN
      lcOperac = 'D';
      lnIdeTab = OLD.BAN_IDENTI;
      lcColumn = 'BAN_NOMBRE';
      lcValorx = OLD.BAN_NOMBRE;
   END
 
   IF (UPDATING) THEN BEGIN
      lcOperac = 'U';
      lnIdeTab = OLD.BAN_IDENTI;
      lcColumn = 'BAN_NOMBRE';
      lcValorx = NEW.BAN_NOMBRE;
   END
 
   INSERT INTO ACTUALIZACIONES
        VALUES(0, :lcUsuari, :ldTiempo, :lcTablax, :lcOperac, :lnIdeTab, :lcColumn, :lcValorx);
```

Parece que MYQSL no soporta en un solo TRIGGER esto:

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE

e igualmente no se como declarar la variable para que esta despues se guarde en la tabla de registro.

Comment: Por favor, ejecuta esta instrucción SQL en tu SGBD: **`SHOW CREATE TRIGGER bi_lista;`** Copia el resultado y pégalo en la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. Sin ver el `TRIGGER` completo es complicado poder ayudarte. Si el TRIGGER no se crea, pon igualmente la instrucción completa con que intentas crearlo. El error puede venir de un `END` no cerrado, de un `;` olvidado o de otra parte. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho buscar encontré la solucion:

-> Antes de `CREATE TRIGGER` se debe escribir `DELIMITER $$`

-> Al finalizar escribir `END$$`

-> En una nueva linea escribir `DELIMITER ;`